# Display Regions in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I have been using a lot of `{$REGION}` in my projects and lost track of them. Is it possible to enum/display these "Regions" in a unit with the Delphi IDE? (like in a list)

Comment: Just search for them in the usual way. CTRL+F, {$REGION}

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hmmm. I thought the IDE maybe had something that just displays all found regions within the unit. Thank you for your comment. I guess I will delete the question then.

Comment: Find in Files will list them all in the search window

Comment: That's what Find in Files does. It generates a list of matches in the search results window.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh it was confusing cause you said it will list them "all" - though you can only search for one.

Answer (score 2):

You could install G-Experts and use the Grep Search functionality on '{$REGION'
Lists all you need and can be saved to a file.

Greetings

Comment: That functionality exists in stock IDE. Why install anything?